# Use a constant value in html file

Tags: angularjs, constants, angular-ng-if

Can anyone tell me how to pass a constant value to html in AngularJS? 
Example: In html file, I have an ng-if condition.

```
<span ng-if="prod.ID">10</span>
```

Here I want to make the value "10" as configurable. 
Something like :

```
<span ng-if="prod.ID == constants.prodID">10</span>
```

Any suggestions?

Thank You in advance.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 4):

First, create a constant:

```
   app.constant("ProductConst", {
      "prodTotal": 10
   });
```

Second, inject it into your controller

```
app.controller('MyController', function ($scope, ProductConst) {
    $scope.productTotal = ProductConst.prodTotal;
}
```

Last, use it in your view:

```
<span  ng-if="prod.ID > productTotal "></span>
```

Comment: so yeah, what I said :')

Comment: Sorry, haven't seen it

Answer (score 3):

1. inject the constant in your controller
2. put the constant on the `$scope`

That should do the trick :-)